# Is there a way to process CRL updates without creating a new socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to create a socket server which includes a CRL, the clients maintain socket connection so restarting or reseting the server socket dissconnects all clients. I would like to maintain a CRL however I dont want to have to restart the server every time the CRL is updated to reset the socket. Does anyone know of a way to update an existing ssl socket?

Server code:

```py
import socket, ssl

from certvalidator import CertificateValidator, ValidationContext

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.verify_flags = ssl.VERIFY_CRL_CHECK_LEAF
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=r"path to ca with crl appended")

context.load_cert_chain(r"path to crt", r"path to key", password='pass') ###############
bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('', 9000))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    sslsoc = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    request = sslsoc.read()
    print(request)
```

Client code:

```py
import socket
import ssl
hostname = '127.0.0.1'
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations(cafile="path to CA")
context.load_cert_chain(r"path to cer", r"path to key", password='pass')
context.check_hostname = False
with socket.create_connection((hostname, 8089)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        ssock.do_handshake()
        print('connected')
        ssock.send(b'122222')
        while True:
            header = ssock.recv(4)
            print(header)
            data = ssock.recv(10000)
            print(header + data)
            print(len(data))
            print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server socket `bindsocket` is not affected from the change of CRL in the first place, since it is a plain TCP socket. All what needs to be changed is the SSL context `context` and this can be done at any time without any changes needed to `bindsocket`. The new SSL context with the changed URL will then be used for the next client when doing the TLS handshake using `context.wrap_socket`.

> restarting or reseting the server socket dissconnects all clients

This is not true. The listener `bindsocket` and the client connection `newsocket` are independent from each other, i.e. closing `bindsocket` has no effect on `newsocket`. Of course, restarting the full server application will disconnect all clients since close of the application will close all sockets.

Comment: I've updated my code as it didn't reflect my real issue, I need to update the server socket context and in my real use case I don't have control over the Client. The issue is if I close the wrapped server socket then the client disconnects, and even then I can't reuse the original TCP socket with an updated context.

Comment: @user210328: Please don't change a question significantly after it was answered. I've answered the question as it was asked. If you wanted to ask something differently then please ask a new question and don't make your question a moving target. That's why I've rolled back your edit to reflect what was originally answered.